# find a specific word from websites page using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
theurl = "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
body_elem = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"_1xnd"})
for word in body_elem:
    c= word.text
    if c == "BBC":
        print(c)
    else:
        print("unable to find the element")
```

I want to find a specific word from the page, so to narrow down the search i got to 'div' with 'class' '_1xnd' then find all texts found in that 'div' then match the given word which is in my case 'BBC' with word found in body.elem then print out  'BBC' but it's not getting the word 'BBC' rather it print out the 'else' part.

Comment: You can use XPATH and get elements that match exact that string or substring (//*[text()='BBC'] or //*[contains(text(), 'BBC')] ) - can replace * for tag element if you want to be more strict

Comment: @Wonka Could you be more clear, it still say unable to locate element

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: @AMC when i run the above sample of code it wont find the word BBC, my Goal is to find the word i give as input if it exist in the page

Comment: I checked against that actual page and the string "BBC" isn't in any of the body text!  It appears in an alt tag

Comment: @DaviLeo What are your criteria for whether something _exist[s] in the page_ ? Also, there appears to be a typo in the code you shared.

Comment: @Vorsprung if you run print(word.text) inside the for loop, it will print out bunch of text found in the body_elem. What i want exactly to find out is to get the word 'BBC' from the texts in body_elem

Comment: @AMC it just search the given word from the specific location of the page . If it failed to find it ,it prints the else statement

Comment: @DaviLeo I’m not sure I understand how that answers the question I raised in my comment, am I missing missing something?

Comment: If I print out all the ``c = word.text`` then I get a bunch of words that do not include the string BBC.  This is because the text of a tag does not include the attributes.  The string BBC only occurs in an alt tag attribute of one of the elements in the section fo div that you have selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a `c == "BBC"` comparison, which checks if `c` is exactly equal to `"BBC"`, which it is obviously not. `c` is the whole text. Instead try: `if "BBC" in c:` which works. `"BBC" in c` checks if "BBC" appears in the string c.

Comment: thank you. But how can i locate the location of the word i found

Comment: use [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp)

Comment: Could you explain it more

Comment: c.find("BBC") returns the index of the first occurence of BBC in your text

Comment: thank you, i found other way to locate the index but i am still unable to find the specific class to locate the word i prefer as there are 5 classes with the name '_1xnd' i wasn't able to select the class which have the word i seek. you can check the class '_1xnd' from Facebook , what i want to find out is the class to the timeline so that i can get the text from that part